# Late 90s or early 00s fantasy show about a girl in a fantasy place with muppet type monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv

The programme in question was on maybe bbc 1 or Sky 1 around 1999/2000 and I remember watching *[The Adventures of Dodo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0fwQrRuI3E)* and *[Conan the Adventurer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Adventurer_(1992_TV_series))* (both cartoons) before.

The show was a 2 or 3 part series and was live action fantasy.
All I can remember is that the main character was a young girl and I think she wakes up in a strange fantasy place and she is greeted by some big muppet like monster I think. She’s scared of them and ends up in their village which I think has been attacked by something evil, so it turns out they aren’t the bad guys. Then she goes on a quest with them.

Another scene I remember is she is with her travelling companions and I think in the story the girl's mother is dead. Anyhow in this scene she is in something like a version of her reality, in her house. It's night and she is tiny; she sees her mother there asleep in bed and tries to call out to her but it's no use. And they carry on through to the next part of their quest.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Sky one shows; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programmes_broadcast_by_Sky_One

Comment: With "Muppet type monsters", my impulse is either Krofft or Henson, but no dice before. I kind of wonder if it might be one of the *The Storyteller* episodes.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I’ve looked into the storyteller episodes and read the descriptions but none of them were it. I did get excited though when I came across storyteller thinking it looked very promising. As for Krofft, I’ll look into that thanks

Comment: I also looked through the sky one list and couldn’t find it. Bugs me that I can remember so little about it

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those two shows weren't on Sky One.

Comment: I’ve been doing some research and I think Conan was on BBC. However, no trace of the show in question. 
I swear it was in 2 or 3 parts, same as Ted Danson - Gullivers Travel format I think. And for some reason I think it might have been Sky 1 but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Banx88 - Dodo I think was on ITV in some regions.

Comment: This of course sounds a lot like *Labyrinth*, which could be mistaken for a show if you just saw a few scenes in it...

Answer (score 2):

The show you're thinking of might be The 10th Kingdom, starring Kimberley Williams as Virginia. She gets transported from New York City to a fairy tale kingdom via a magic mirror.

[image]

I came across this question while trying to remember this show myself. I also checked the Wikipedia list of Sky One programmes but managed to miss it as it was the first one on the list!